# How to set hbase HMaster host?

Tags: eclipse, client, hbase

I wrote a program in Eclipse to test the remote connection to HBase. This is modified from [HBase Example API Usage](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/package-summary.html). It does very basic things: connect to hbase, drop a table if exists, then create a new one. Here's the code :

```
public class TableTest {

    private static Configuration conf = null;

    static{
        conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum","192.168.12.120"); 
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort","2181"); 
        //conf.set("hbase.master", "192.168.12.120:12000"); // not work

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String tableName = "hbase_table";
        try {
            Connection connection = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
            Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();
            HTableDescriptor table = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
            table.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("info"));
            if(admin.tableExists(table.getTableName())){
                admin.disableTable(table.getTableName());
                admin.deleteTable(table.getTableName());
            }
            admin.createTable(table);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got some problems for making the connection work. The message is the following. On one side, the program searched the **HRegionServer** at `192.168.12.120` on port 16020, on another side, it searched the **HMaster** at localhost `127.0.0.1` on port 12000. This broke the connection, because both HRegionServer and HMaster are running at `192.168.12.120`.

```
1294 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Use SIMPLE authentication for service ClientService, sasl=false
1311 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Connecting to /192.168.12.120:16020
1357 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Reading reply sessionid:0x14f39c8a9f20060, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,3  replyHeader:: 5,1210,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: s{4,4,1439021727692,1439021727692,0,116,0,0,0,16,1191} 
1360 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Reading reply sessionid:0x14f39c8a9f20060, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,4  replyHeader:: 6,1210,0  request:: '/hbase/master,F  response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a3132303030ffffffc4ffffffbbffffffbcffffffd251ffffffb2ffffffe0ffffffb950425546a15a96c6f63616c686f737410ffffffe05d18ffffff89ffffffc5ffffffa1fffffff1fffffff42910018ffffff8a7d,s{1170,1170,1440125319355,1440125319355,0,0,0,94357651205521495,57,0,1170} 
1369 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Use SIMPLE authentication for service MasterService, sasl=false
1369 DEBUG [2015-08-21 11:08:49]  Connecting to localhost/127.0.0.1:12000
```

So how to set hbase master host at `192.168.12.120` ? Can somebody help ?
Here're 2 docs for the configuration :

- [Apache HBase ™ Reference Guide: 7. Default Configuration](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#config.files)
- [Github: apache/hbase/.../hbase-default.xml](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/resources/hbase-default.xml)